# Add function to specific WordPress page

Tags: wordpress

I wrote this code in `function.php` of my `wordpress theme`:

```
remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
function wpse_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 40;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

How can I load this code only for a specific WordPress page, in particular page-id 5580?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
if( is_page( 5580 ) {
    remove_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wp_trim_excerpt');
    add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'wpse_custom_wp_trim_excerpt');
    function wpse_excerpt_length( $length ) {
        return 40;
    }

    add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'wpse_excerpt_length', 999 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use **is_page()** and pass **page slug** for the same ..you can pass **page slug , title , Id** anything in this function

Example if your id is - **5580** then use **is_page('5580')**

but the_excerpt is mostly used for blog so if you are looking for blog then use **is_home()** for the same

Refer below link for more details - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/